# What is A B::* func() defining?

Tags: c++

A now deleted question had something similar to this:

```
struct A { };
struct B {
    A read();
};

A B::* read()
{
    return A{};
}
```

This code will give the error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘A’ to ‘A B::*’ in return
  return A{};
```

As we can see, this is not an out-of-class definition of `read()` but defining a non-member function which returns an `A B::*`. What exactly is an `A B::*` in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A B::*` means "pointer to data member of `B` with type `A`. For example:

```
struct B {
  A x;
};

...

B b;
A B::*ptr = &B::x; // ptr is the variable declared here.
b.*ptr = foo; // same as b.x = foo;
```

In your code's context, it would mean a function (not a member function) returning a pointer to member. You could have

```
A B::*foo() {
  return &B::x;
}

...

A B::*ptr = foo();
```